# Computer puzzle using functions

Tags: computer-puzzle

Write the function that operates as stated below:

In: "get"

Out: "2069"

In: "more"

Out: “5191716"

In: "insight"

Out: "209912231915"

Hint: First, figure out how the function works

& then implement it.

Comment: If (in=="get") return "2069" and so on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> myString.reverse().split(",").map(this.mid(index,1).toASCII()-64+index (pseudo-code)
>
>  Or, in plain English, reverse the string, convert to A1Z26 and add the position index, starting at $0$. So:
>
>  $get\to teg \to (20+0)(5+1)(7+2) \to 2069$
>  $more\to erom \to (5+0)(18+1)(15+2)(13+3) \to 5191716$
>  $insight\to thgisni \to (20+0)(8+1)(7+2)(9+3)(19+4)(14+5)(9+6) \to 209912231915$

Working JavaScript:

> ```
>  function code(str) {
>  arr=str.split("").reverse().map((x,i)=>str.charCodeAt(str.length-i-1)-64+i);
>  return arr.join("")
>  }
>
>
>  code("GET")
>  "2069"
>  code("MORE")
>  "5191716"
>  code("INSIGHT")
>  "209912231915"
> ```

Comment: You could replace `str.charCodeAt(...)` with `str.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(...)` to make it work with uppercase and lowercase inputs.

Comment: Better still just use `x.charCodeAt() % 32 + i`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below:

```
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String input = "insight";
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString()
    for(int i = 0; i < reverse.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(alphabet.indexOf(reverse.charAt(i))+1+i+"");
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Python, one-liner:

```
''.join(str(i+1+ord(c)-ord('a')) for i,c in enumerate(s[::-1]))
```

or if you want to golf it, fold the `+1` into the optional second argument `enumerate(..., step)` :

```
''.join(str(i+ord(c)-ord('a')) for i,c in enumerate(s[::-1],1))
```

or just hardwire the ASCII constants `ord('a') == 97`, `` ord('`') == 96 ``